# How Should Multiple Checksums Be Performed On the Same Data?

Tags: integrity, udp, checksum

I am using CRC32 to verify the integrity of received UDP packets. Along with the generator polynomial, the sender will also specify how many checksums to perform on the sent data, as well as what iteration to start at in its body. How should this be done?

For example, say I am sent this data

```
100100001
```

And this key

```
1101
```

Then I would normally do a CRC check like this

```
     _______________
1101 ) 100100001
     + 1101,,,,,
       ----,,,,,
       01000,,,,
      + 1101,,,,
        ----,,,,
        01010,,,
       + 1101,,,
         ----,,,
         01110,,
        + 1101,,
          ----,,
          001101
          + 1101
            ----
               0
```

At this point, I can verify that my data has not been changed or altered since the remainder is zero. However, if the sender specifies that multiple checksums should be done from a certain starting point, where exactly do I go from here?